# PowerShell - working with multiple decimal points (i.e driver versions)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, powershell

I'm trying to make a script to update machines that are using old drivers.

I can get the devices I want to target like this:`Get-WmiObject win32_pnpsigneddriver |where {$_.DeviceID -match "VEN_8086&DEV_0083"}`

Now the current driver version for this is 17.0.2 but the machine I'm testing on has version 14.1.1.3 installed.

I want my line of code to use something like this:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_pnpsigneddriver |
where {$_.DeviceID -match "VEN_8086&DEV_0083" -AND $_.DriverVersion -le 17.0.2.0}
```

that fails of course, as you can't have two decimal points in a number. If change my code to be:
`Get-WmiObject win32_pnpsigneddriver  |where {$_.DeviceID -match "VEN_8086&DEV_0083" -AND $_.DriverVersion -le 17.0}` then I get the answer I want but of course when version 17.0.9.9 is out and my target machine is running 17.0.2.0 then the driver won't get updated.

Any ideas on how I can compare numbers like this?

Comment: What have you tried? Googling for `compare version numbers powershell` gave me https://www.cupfighter.net/2009/06/powershell-comparing-version-numbers as the top hit which suggests using Powershell's built-in `[version]` type. Does that not work for you?

Comment: I tried just what I've posted above, and also Googling for `comparing numbers with multiple decimal places` - but that gave no positive results.
Thanks for the link - I've not heard of that compareto option before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also strongly type to [version]. (Shay Levy post)

```
Get-WmiObject win32_pnpsigneddriver | where {$_.DeviceID -match "VEN_8086&DEV_0083" -and [version]$_.DriverVersion -lt [version]'1.7.0.2'}
```